# Assistance with bomb throwing mechanics akin to Zelda 2D

Tags: collision-detection

Does anyone have a good algorithm for managing the carrying and throwing of bombs? I've attempted to find a tutorial and can't find anything that covers the subject matter. I'm just looking for a very high-level algorithm; the coding I can handle.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: "Carrying" as in holding over your head? What kind/part of throwing? "Zelda 2D" covers games from the 1980's to a couple years ago, so you'll need to be a tad bit more specific.